# how to add a picture onto the interface..?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, user-interface

I want to display a picture that is of jpeg type onto my interface. I want that picture to be displayed when my program is being executed. I'm doing this:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LoadRecords();
     Image.FromFile("@ C:\Users\cAndyb0eMeh\Documents\Downloads\images.jpeg");        
}
```

But this doesn't work.  I get errors.

Comment: Adding the error message to your post will get you much further, in general.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (your @ is in the wrong place):

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
 LoadRecords();      
 pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Andy Meh\Documents\Downloads\images.jpeg");
}
```

Comment: +1 although the string seems to have got mangled in your answer. you also need to remove the initial space

Comment: ok.. but.. is the code correct for inserting a picture? and yeah.. before doing doing that i need a picture box so that it stores a picture.. here.. the picture is not going any where

Comment: that is true. how about giving that a try and then if you have any specific problems, ask?

Comment: @Abid - check my post for how to display the image.

Comment: @Abid, drop a picture box onto your form and just add just set the Image to the Image you've just loaded, as above

Answer (score 0):

You'll need somewhere to put that picture, like a [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) control. You can one to your form from Visual Studio's ToolBox. When you add one, it is named `PictureBox1` by default. So, in your form load event, you'd have:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("@ C:\Users\cAndyb0eMeh\Documents\Downloads\images.jpeg");
```

The way you're doing it now, the image doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: i do the same thing as above into the picture box? i mean the code is correct?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use "\\" for mentioning the path.

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile"c:\\Users\cAndyb0eMeh\\Documents\\Downloads\\images.jpeg");

Comment: Not when you prepend it with @ before the quotation marks. This marks it as a verbatim string literal and escape characters are ignored.

Comment: I think so. I have only used the version which I have mentioned above in which there is no '@'.